# Arch udev rule not triggering

Tags: usb, arch-linux, udev

I am trying to trigger xsecurelock upon removal of a yubikey. This is done as follows:

file: `90-yubikey.rules`:

```
ACTION="remove", SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", RUN+="/bin/xsecurelock"
```

I then ran `sudo udev --reload`, and removed the yubikey, but nothing happened.

I used `udevadm --property` to confirm that udev detected the removal of the device, and the the idVendor was indeed 1050.

N.B. I am aware that running `/bin/xsecurelock` will lock as root, which is not ideal, but I'll fix that once I get the rule triggering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATTRS{} doesn't match udev properties – it matches sysfs attributes, which are a completely different thing. It directly reads files from the device's subdirectory under /sys every time it is used, and the subdirectory for your Yubikey simply no longer exists once it has been unplugged.

The values you see in 'udevadm monitor --property' are stored in udev database and can be matched using ENV{} or ENVS{} during removal. So instead of `ATTRS{idVendor}` you should use `ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}`.

Aside from that, there are rules to writing udev rules:

1. Udev rules cannot start long-running processes; 'RUN' is meant for helper tools which prepare the device, so all device handling waits for the it to exit.
2. Udev rules cannot run anything X11-related, as they don't have the address of the X server.

A common workaround is to use `RUN+="systemctl ..."` to start the program as a systemd service.

The most appropriate method in your case is to use `RUN+="loginctl lock-sessions"` and let your desktop environment (or xss-lock) handle the launching of your screensaver.